# Django rest framework post item to db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, nested

I'm working on my school project and I'm totally stuck. I'm newbie on django. Trying to create an nmap reporter api. I have an JSON data with nested object. I need to save this JSON data to my database. But I cant. My data is this:

```
[
    {
        "host": "192.168.1.8",
        "hostname": "",
        "hostname_type": "",
        "state": "open",
        "service": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "port": "80",
                "product": "Apache httpd",
                "version": "2.2.8",
                "extrainfo": "(Ubuntu) DAV/2",
                "vulnerabilities": [
                    {"name":"CVE Example","version":"2.42"},
                    {"name":"CVE Example","version":"2.42"},
                    {"name":"CVE Example","version":"2.42"},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But my saved data is:

```
        [
    {
        "host": "192.168.1.8",
        "hostname": "",
        "hostname_type": "",
        "state": "open",
        "service": [
            {
                "name": "http",
                "port": "80",
                "product": "Apache httpd",
                "version": "2.2.8",
                "extrainfo": "(Ubuntu) DAV/2",
                "vulnerabilities": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me?Thanks. 
My models and serializers:

I have 3 models for this.

```
class Service(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = 'tblService'

result = models.ForeignKey(Result, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service')
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
port = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
product = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
extrainfo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

This is service model for service section on JSON.

```
class Vulnerability(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = 'tblVulnerability'
Service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="vulnerabilities")
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
priority = models.CharField(max_length=255)
version = models.CharField(max_length=255)
url = models.TextField()
```

This model for vulnerabilities section.

```
class Result(models.Model):
host = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
hostname_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
state = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
```

This model my parent model.

And my serializers:

```
class ScanPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
service = ServiceSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Result
    fields = ['host', 'hostname', 'hostname_type', 'state', 'service']

def create(self, validated_data):
    service_data = validated_data.pop('service')
    result = Result.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for servic_data in service_data:
        Service.objects.create(result=result, **servic_data)
    return result


class VulnerabilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.Vulnerability
    fields = ['pk','name', 'priority', 'version', 'url']


class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
vulnerabilities = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.Service
    fields = ['name', 'port', 'product', 'version', 'extrainfo', 'vulnerabilities']

def create(self, validated_data):
    vulnerability_data = validated_data.pop('vulnerabilities')
    service = models.Service.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for vul_data in vulnerability_data:
        Vulnerability.objects.create(Service=service, **vul_data)
    return service

def get_vulnerabilities(self,obj):
    qset = Vulnerability.objects.all()
    return [VulnerabilitySerializer(m).data for m in qset]
```

**Edit:** I changed some section in my code. And now I got error.

> Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use vulnerabilities.set() instead.

Comment: it seems <vulnerability_data = validated_data.pop('vulne')> this is null. Can you check?

Comment: I checked and change something. Now I got error. I edited my answer can u check? @engin_ipek

Comment: And now it seems pop is not working. Can you print out validated_data and share in comment

Comment: Btw why does the Service field in Vulnerability model start with an uppercase letter? It should start with a lowercase letter by convention

Comment: Ooh thanks for advice. I changed it. validated_data's result little longer for comment https://pastebin.com/BvVehqCB I upload to pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

In `ServiceSerializer` change `vulnerabilities` from `MethodField` to :

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vulnerabilities = VulnerabilitySerializer(many=True)
```

And remove `get_vulnerabilities` method.

This worked for me.

Comment: Isn't worked :( I made this changes and got same error. So I deleted the related_name of foreign_key. And now I got new error this say--> TypeError: Service() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vulnerabilities'